# Fill Action When Site open

Tags: javascript, jquery, tampermonkey

I need a help to Fill the Action Filed For Example ("2page") when i open the Website

What i want

```
<form name="AGXBFS" id="AGXBFS" action="2page" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

What i Got is :

```
<form name="AGXBFS" id="AGXBFS" action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

what i tried

```
$('#AGXBFS').submit(function (event)
{
    var action = 'appointment.php';
    // compute action here...
    $(this).attr('action', action);
});
```

this work but only when i click i want it to change without Clicking any Ideas how to do that With Java/Jquery

Comment: Why not just `$("#AGXBFS").attr('action', '2page');` instead of using the `.submit()` method